# Get id's of all child elements with a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the id's of the 'vehicle' class from the `<ul>`. How can I get that using jquery/javascript? Can it be done with iterating through all the elements? Thanks in advance.

```
<ul id="ulList">
  <li id="car" class="vehicle">
  <li id="bus" class="vehicle">
  <li id="cat" class="animal">
  <li id="dog" class="animal">
  <li id="bike" class="vehicle">
  <li id="monkey" class="animal">
</ul>
```

Comment: _Can it be done with iterating through all the elements?_ have you tried it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [**map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Also, correct your HTML markup like in the snippet(`class=""`).

Finally, use [**.get()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) if you need a true JavaScript array (instead of a jQuery collection of strings — jQuery's collections [sets] usually contain DOM elements, but *can* contain anything).

```js
var ids = $('#ulList .vehicle').map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('id');
  }).get();

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulList">
  <li id="car" class="vehicle"></li>
  <li id="bus" class="vehicle"></li>
  <li id="cat" class="animal"></li>
  <li id="dog" class="animal"></li>
  <li id="bike" class="vehicle"></li>
  <li id="monkey" class="animal"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @AmmarCSE i guess `.get()` should also be there is you are using `.map()` of jquery.

Comment: @Jai ...but would need polyfilled for older browsers. jQuery covers that requirement

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

`vehicleIds` is an array to which you `push` all the ids of elements whose class is `vehicle`.

```
var vehicleIds = [];
$(".vehicle").each(function(){
   vehicleIds.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
alert(vehicleIds);
```

Then I `alert` the array at the end.

Comment: I made some small changes but that explanation helps, thanks!

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan help for good is always appreciated ,Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

As there are already other answers with jQuery, here is an alternative using vanila Javascript:

```js
var vehicles = document.querySelectorAll("ul#ulList > li.vehicle");
var ids = [].map.call(vehicles, function(elem) {
  return elem.id;  
});
console.log(ids);
```

```html
<ul id="ulList">
  <li id="car" class="vehicle">
  <li id="bus" class="vehicle">
  <li id="cat" class="animal">
  <li id="dog" class="animal">
  <li id="bike" class="vehicle">
  <li id="monkey" class="animal">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div','#main').each(function(){
  array.push($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Here div is the element whose children's id have to be pushed in an array & '#main' is the id of that div.

Hope this will help you.